# Algebra structure of $\mathbb{k}^S$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to write explicitly how the algebra structure of $\mathbb{k}^S$ works on its basis elements, where $\mathbb{k}$ is a field and $S$ any finite set.

Let's call its basis $B:=\{e_s:s \in S\}$, where the elements are defined as $e_s: t \mapsto \delta_{s,t}$. Now, I would like to show that

- $e_s \cdot e_t = \delta_{s,t}e_s$
- $1_{\mathbb{k}^S} = \sum_{s \in S}e_s$

given that, if $f,g \in \mathbb{k}^S, (f\cdot g)(s) =f(s)g(s)$ and $(f+g)(s) =f(s)+g(s)$.

My attempt for the first equality is that $e_s \cdot e_t (x) = e_s(x)e_t(x)=\delta_{s,x}\delta_{t,x}$ which is not zero if $x=s$, so $e_s(x)e_t(x)=\delta_{t,s}$ but it's not right.
For the second equality I can't link the basis elements with the unit. Shouldn't it be $1_{\mathbb{k}^S}=1_{\mathbb{k}}$?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: $1_\Bbb{k}$ isn't an element of $\Bbb{k}^S$, is it?

Comment: @OttavioBartenor it isn't. It is an element of $\mathbb{k}$. The unit element of $\mathbb{k}^S$ is indeed a map $1_{\mathbb{k}^s}: s \mapsto 1_{\mathbb{k}}$

Comment: That's what I'm saying, that's the key of your question. Let me be clearer in a complete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's name your algebra $A:=\Bbb{k}^S$. For any $f\in A$ we have, by definition, $f(t)=f(s)\delta_{s,t}\in\Bbb{k}$.
(Just think of $f\in A$ as a vector, and $f(t)$ as its $t$-th component.)

Thus, for any $x\in S$, $$(e_s\cdot e_t)(x)=e_s(x)e_t(x)=\delta_{s,x}\delta_{x,t}=\delta_{s,t}\delta_{s,x}=\delta_{s,t}e_s(x),$$
that is, $e_s\cdot e_t=\delta_{s,t}e_s$.

For the second equality, notice that $(f\cdot e_s)(x)=f(x)\delta_{x,s}=f(s)$. Repeat for all $s\in S$ and apply the distributive property to check that

$$f\cdot\sum_{s\in S}e_s\ (x)=\sum_{s\in S}(f\cdot e_s)(x)= \sum_{s\in S}f(x)\delta_{x,s}=f(x)\sum_{s\in S}\delta_{x,s}=f(x)=(f\cdot1_A)(x),$$
that is, $1_A=\sum_{s\in S}e_s$.